# Swift passing an object with a constant in segue

Tags: swift

Say an object with the following init declaration:

```
class Transaction {
    let title: String
    init (title: String) {
        self.title = title
    } 
}
```

I want to write the following in `prepareForSegue`:

```
destinationVC.transaction = transactions[row] as Transaction
```

How do I declare `transaction` in the destinationVC as it wont let me instantiate it without the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write something like this in your destination vc's class:

```
var transaction: Transaction!
```

So you can pass a variable in `prepareForSegue`.

For two reasons we use `!` (inherently unwrapped optional type) here.

- We don't have direct control of view controller's instantiation process, meaning we cannot use its `-init` here. As a result we cannot declare as type `Transaction` and pass a value to the `-init` .
- It is guaranteed for the variable to have a value if you have passed in one in `-prepareForSegue:`. Declaring it as `Transaction?` and unwrapping every time we use add unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `transactions` in main controller must be declared as `Array<Transaction>`.

The variable `transaction` in destinationVC must be declared as `Transaction`